# When can/should 'quite a few' be used instead of 'some'?

Tags: single-word-requests

> You will see a lot of mistakes from top to bottom of my thread. These
>   may be a burden because I have quite a few questions which needed to
>   be answered.

Why was *quite* used before *a few questions*? What's the difference between using *some questions* instead of *quite a few questions*?

Comment: "quite a few" is idiomatic for "many".  "Some" is not as many as "quite a few".

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thanks. Look up a dictionary, [Quite a few](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quite-a-few?q=quite+a+few).

Comment: You cannot use 'quite' instead of 'some'.  If you did, the sentence would be, "*These may be a burden because I have some a few questions...*"  That makes no sense. The word 'quite' in your text is part of the idiom, 'quite a few'.

Answer (score 2):

> Why quite has been used before a few questions?

I think "quite" is used to highlight that there are more than "few questions" in a given context.

> If I use some questions instead of quite a few questions, what
>   differences will be appeared?

Using "some questions" would not highlight how many (i.e. not really defined/cared about)...whether if you say "quite a few questions" it signifies your stress on the number of questions being more than a usual "few" in that context.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the word *quite*. Many English speakers use this word idiomatically, but if hard pressed, they probably couldn't tell you what it means.

This word is simply another English way of saying "thoroughly" or "fully" or "completely".

*I'm **quite** perplexed by this question.*

*I was **quite** lonely going to the movies by myself.*

*I'm **quite** pleased with the way this recipe worked!*

*My friend looked **quite** ridiculous in his Halloween costume.*

It can also be used in a 'negative' context to mean "not completely", etc.

*I'm **not quite** convinced he's telling the truth.*

*I'm **not quite** full. May I have another bowl of soup?*